# Regex to match url with postfix?

Tags: regex, django

So I've got a somewhat interesting regex challenge. Consider the following [django url routing] regex:

```
(/(?P<required_part>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))(/(?P<optional_part>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))?/postfix
```

I have a second URL as follows (note the lack of postfix):

```
(/(?P<required_part>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))(/(?P<optional_part>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))?
```

In words, I've got a required part, followed by an optional part, followed by a postfix *that is also matched by the optional part.* I'd like all URLs that end in the postfix to get matched by the first one, and all that don't to get matched by the second one. The problem is that in all cases the postfix gets captured by the optional part, and the second pattern matches.

How should I approach this? Bonus points if the solution doesn't introduce database injection vulnerabilities when I inject this into a database.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use the (?P<>) notation instead of just using normal capturing groups?  Also, would \w be a sufficient replacement for your use of [a-zA-Z0-9\-]?

Comment: I use that notation to allow django to pass the captured text into my view methods. Also I prefer to use the full regex because I find using shorthand makes the code less readable and more difficult to reason about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either limit the scope of the second regex by adding a `$` to the end, thus making the second regex only match urls that have two directories in its path, or you can add a negative lookahead to the end of the second regex to search only for urls that do not have postfix as the third directory:

```
^(/(?P<required_part>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))(/(?P<optional_part>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+))?(?!/postfix)
```

I would also suggest adding a `^` to the start of your regexes. Without it the above regex can backtrack and match `/foo/bar/postfix/baz`.